# Ambiguous Function Call: Passing a template parameter to one of many override functions

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

The following is an abbreviated version of the code I'm working on. I'm getting the following error:

> Call to member function 'AddValue' is ambiguous

I'm using a template function because I need treat certain types in certain cases differently, thus the template helps me avoid duplicate code.

```
struct Event
{
    void AddValue(const std::uint32_t& inValue)
    {
        // Ex: make inValue a string and insert key value pair in a map
    }

    void AddValue(const float& inValue)
    {
        // Ex: set restrictions on the precision of the float and insert key value pair in a map
    }
};

template <typename TValue>
void manipulateEvent(const char* inCategory, const TValue& inValue)
{
    Event e; 
    // other operations on "e"
    e.AddValue(inValue);  
    Send(e); 
}

void Log(const char* inCategory, const float& inValue)
{
   manipulateEvent(inCategory, inValue); 
}

// I believe this might be the source of the issue. Passing NULL into the
// template parameter in cases where there is nothing to pass. 
// Without this it compiles fine. However, I do need this case. 
void Log(const char* inCategory)
{
   manipulateEvent(inCategory, NULL); 
}

void Log(const char* inCategory, const std::uint32_t& inValue)
{
   manipulateEvent(inCategory, inValue); 
}
```

```
main()
{
   Log("category", 10.5); 
   Log("category"); 
   Log("category", 10);
}
```

Is there something I'm missing that would allow me to continue this train of thought? Or are there any recommendations about how to achieve the same goal, but differently?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Why do you expect your program to run with function call not matching the function signature?

Comment: This isn't verbatim my code. I was simplifying it to only include the source of my issue. Including my code would be way too long. Regardless, while trying to craft my question I introduce careless mistakes. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide an appropriate `Log` for the null char* overload

```
void Log(const char* inCategory, const char*)
{
  manipulateEvent(inCategory, nullptr);
}
```

Then resolve the ambiguity by being explicit with what you're passing to `Log`.

Either with literal suffixes `f` and `u`

```
Log("category", 10.5f);
Log("category", nullptr);
Log("category", 10u);
```

or by casting

```
Log("category", static_cast<float>(10.5));
Log("category", nullptr);
Log("category", static_cast<std::uint32_t>(10));
```

And always prefer `nullptr` to NULL.